# Weird conflicts with Chrome

Tags: software-installation, google-chrome

I'm running 14.04. I have Chrome installed and when I try to install Redshift through the software center, I get "the following items will be removed" prompt and there are three items:

```
google-chrome-stable:i386

libappindicator1:i386

libindicator7:i386
```

I thought this was some weird isolated problem with Redshift, but now I'm trying to use Hamachi, installing with these instructions: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Hamachi

And at the second step installing Haguchi, when I type

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install haguichi
```

it does a bunch of stuff, but then stops and says (among other things) that the following packages will be removed, and lists the exact three packages above.

??? What's going on? How do I fix? How do I even begin to diagnose? I have no model of why this would be happening.

Edit:

```
uname -i
```

simply gives

```
x86_64
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `uname -i` terminal command.

Comment: @Pilot6 and done

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You installed a wrong version of Chrome. You have a 64-bit system, but you installed a 32-bit version of Chrome.

Uninstall Chrome by

```
 sudo apt-get remove google-chrome-stable:i386
```

Then [download](https://www.google.com/chrome/browser/desktop/) and install a 64-bit version.

Comment: Cool, this works. Why did this happen, though? Why does installing 32-bit Chrome cause problems with a few seemingly random programs?

Comment: That is a good question. But it is a dependency issue. I can't give a precise answer right away. But generally it is not a good idea to install 32-bit apps to 64-bit systems unless there is no other option.